# I need to manipulate millions of data from a text file and after applying some of the queries i need another file using file input and output stream

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

i have a java code whose functioning is it readers a file using file input stream and after applying some conditions give another file using file output stream

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class Files {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File file = new File("File1.txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            File write = new File("File2.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(write, true);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = line.split("#");
                if (Integer.parseInt(arr[0]) >= 10000) {
                    out.write(arr[1]);
                    out.newLine();
                }

            }
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
            br.close();
            out.close();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

if I want to read millions of data from file and write millions of data in another file how can I edit my code in that case to make my code run fast
I want to make my code fast so that I can fetch or manipulate millions of data

Comment: General performance advice: first decide whether the program really is too slow. If yes, measure performance. There are profiling tools that can tell you where your program spends its time. Then replace the bottleneck with a faster version (or ask us "How can I improve part XY of my program?"), showing the profiling results. Without profiling, performance recommendations are wrong in at least 90% of cases.

Comment: I just want to ask how can I improve my code performance so that i wont take much time to manipulate data in the file